# Google AppEngine createUploadUrl in node

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php, google-appengine-node

In PHP, it is really easy to create an upload url with an endpoint that get's hit after the file is uploaded. [Documentation Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/user_upload)

```
$options = ['gs_bucket_name' => $my_bucket];
$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload/handler', $options);
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do this in Node because I can't seem to figure out how.

Even some documentation on how to do it via a http request would suffice.

Comment: Is [this](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/File#getSignedUrl) what you were looking for, or I didn't understand it?

Comment: @Mangu [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/user_upload) is what I am speaking about but I need it for node. It isn't about accessing a file but allowing a user to upload a file via a google URL